# JUnit test error when I run it

Tags: java, junit

I have an error when run the JUnit test

```
public class DamActionsTester 
{
    private DamActions damAction;
    private final Integer defualtRelease = 50;
    private final Integer damCapacity = 1053;
    private final Integer jobDuration = 14;
    private WaterLog log;

@Before
public void newDamAtctions() throws SimulationException
{
    damAction = new DamActions(damCapacity, defualtRelease, jobDuration, log);
}
```

in here, JUnit test says

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at asgn1Solution.DamActions.<init>(DamActions.java:37)
    at asgn1Solution.DamActionsTester.newDamAtctions(DamActionsTester.java:23)
```

have error such as like that. here is my  part error

```
damLog.addEntry(damCapacity/2);
```

for that, how can I fix it to run it?

Comment: can u share ur DamAction constructore code

Answer (score 0):

It seams `log` is null when passed into the constructor:

```
private WaterLog log;
```

it gets never initialized, right?